# Error in correlate() : could not find function "correlate"

Tags: r, tidyr

I am trying to use `correlate()` from the `corrr` package. But R keeps throwing the error in the title:

`Error in correlate() : could not find function "correlate"`

I downloaded the corrr package several times and I am unable to understand the reason why I'm getting this error. Help me, please!

I am using `correlation()` from `easystats` on the side. I am suspecting that they are interfering each other's work but I don't know how I can find it out.

Also, the reason why I am trying to use `correlate()` is that `correlation()` keeps giving me weird results. I can reproduce most of the significant r and p values using Jamovi but the non-significant p's are almost always >.99. That's why I wanted to try `correlate(`) for once!

Comment: Did you load the package with `library(corrr)`? Maybe try `corrr::correlate()` when you call the function.

Comment: You download and install the package once. You need to load it into your environment with `library(corrr)` each new session where you want to use it.

Comment: `corrr::correlate()` worked. I was using `require(corrr)` but it wasn't working then. Thank you so much!